# What's the exact meaning of the word "nows"?

Tags: definition

I've been reading an article from Newsela, and there was a sentence that goes

> "The Centers for Disease Control and Prevention, or CDC, changed its guidelines the week of March 16. It **nows** says that hospitals should try to reuse surgical masks or have workers wear one through an entire shift."

I understand the meaning of the sentence, and I also get that '**nows**' means similar to '**nowadays**'. But no dictionary gives the meaning of the word '**nows**'. I'm starting to wonder whethere the word really exists.

The only search result I found was from wikitionary(https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nows). It says "*nows:
plural of now*" But from what I understand, nows in the sentence above is an adverb, and adverb can not have a plural form.

Is *nows* a word?

Is it a short form for *nowadays*?

If it is, then why can't I find it from the dictionary?

Comment: As a noun, it's a word (the plural of the noun "now"), but most dictionaries don't include regular plurals.  "Now" is usually uncountable, but there is a rare specialised use that is countable, according to Wiktionary ("(countable, chiefly in phenomenology) A particular instant in time, as perceived at that instant").  In the sentence you found, however, "now" is the word used (as an adverb) and the final "s" is simply a typo, as the answer says.

Answer (score 4):

It's just a typo. It should be "now".